# Start-Job not completing robocopy task

Tags: powershell, robocopy, start-job

When executing this script **not** using `Start-Job`, there are no issues. Files copy from source to destination, one directory at a time, but the amount of time it takes is too long. So I am attempting to implement parallel execution through `Start-Job`.

The script executes without errors, and the individual jobs show as completed, but the files are not being copied to the source. I suspect this has something to do with `$null` variables passing to the job.

I have tried for hours to get this to work, switching the script around, adjusting the script block, flags, etc., but nothing is working.

```
Param(
    [string]$env = 'test',
    [string]$directory = 'F:\Backup_Job'
)

# Set job variables
CD $directory
$servers = Import-Csv .\servers.csv
$query = Get-Content .\Get_Server.txt -Raw
$excludedFiles = Import-Csv .\excludedFiles.csv

$jobs = foreach ($server in $servers) {
    if ($server.env.Trim() -eq $env) {
        Write-Host "Starting copy job for $($server.servername)"
        Start-Job -Name "Copyjob $($server.servername)" -ScriptBlock {
            Param($server, $excludedFiles, $directory, $query)
            # Server and bak variables
            $sqlServer = $server.servername.Trim()
            $filepath = $server.baksource.Trim()

            # Job variables
            $bakserver = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $sqlServer -Database 'master' -QueryTimeout 100
            $baksource = "\\$($bakserver.server)\$($filepath)"
            $bakdest = $server.bakdest.Trim()

            $continue = Test-Path -Path $baksource

            if ($continue) {
                robocopy $baksource $bakdest "*.bak" /XF $excludedFiles.filename /XO /NP /ETA /W:1 /B /XX /R:3
            }
        } -ArgumentList $server, $excludedFiles, $directory, $query
    }
}
```

Comment: Double check the results of your SQL query and all variables to ensure they're populated. Some Write-Verbose -Verbose may clear it up.

Comment: Did you mean to use `Invoke-Command` to run robocopy on each server instead of `Start-Job`? I don't see the benefit of running multiple robocopy instances in parallel on your machine.

Comment: If you suspect that the problem is caused by null-valued parameters: verify it and have the scriptblock exit with an error if that's the case.

Comment: +1 for `Invoke-Command`, going to be much faster as well if you run them with the `-InDisconnectedSession` parameter because then you can save that session to a variable and retrieve the results with `Get-PSSession` (might be `Receive-PSSession`, still asleep this morning :P). Especially helpful if you have latency in your environment this won't kill the invoke after 1 quick moment of disconnect.